# MP3 s not playing in mobile browsers

Tags: object, mp3, embed, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have page where I am allowing myusers to listen music online everything works just fine in pc but when I try to check in nokia symbian, blackberry Android nothing plays

I am using flash MP3 player and my simple codes are here.

I am interested in playing in all mobiles as my main target is mobile users so any idea how can I play them all even in old nokia symbian mobiles will be a great help

All mobiles are supporting JavaScript as I can browse complicated websites with nokia blackberry and Android but only issue is MP3. Any suggestion to play in all mobile phone is welcome.

My live site http://way2enjoy.com/rstadmin/listenmusicmobile/1528\

My code

```
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="audioplayer_1" style="outline: none" data="http://way2enjoy.com/js/player/player.swf" width="500" height="24" id="audioplayer_1"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="flashvars" value="soundFile=uploads/userfiles/201206/1120_56_584iq.preview.mp3&amp;titles=Hanuman Chalisa by Gulshan Kumar&amp;artists=claim_your_money&amp;autostart=yes&amp;loop=yes&amp;playerID=audioplayer_1"></object><script type="text/javascript" src="http://way2enjoy.com/js/player/audio-player.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    AudioPlayer.setup("http://way2enjoy.com/js/player/player.swf", {  
        width: 500  
    });  
    AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", {  
    soundFile: "http://way2enjoy.com/uploads/userfiles/201206/1120_56_584iq.preview.mp3",  
    titles: "Hanuman Chalisa by Gulshan Kumar",  
    artists: "claim_your_money",  
    autostart: "yes",
    loop: "yes"
    }); 
        });
        </script>
```

I am interested in playing in mobile only but I want all mobiles including older nokia symbian etc.

Answer (score 0):

Newest Android phones don't have Flash support anymore...
Also the Flash player needs to support mp3 (I don't know if that is default)

You should try different solutions for different phones. You can do this by checking if the object is support (as last resort the User Agent string).